# How do I deploy multiple instances of the same service type per node?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a stateless service that is "micro" enough that I would like to run several of them per node that I have in my fabric cluster. This is especially true since it seems that one node is equivalent to one VM in the world of service fabric (except for the local development cluster). By default it seems that Service Fabric expects a maximum of one of each service to be running on a given node. If I set the InstanceCount to be greater than the number of available nodes, I will get a warning to the effect of there are not enough nodes available to fulfill to requested number of instances.

I can work around this by creating multiple named services of a given service type and set the InstanceCount individually for each named service. Is this the correct way to accomplish this or have I missed something obvious?

Comment: What do expect to gain by running multiple instances on one node? It won't give you better performance, as services aren't limited/capped in their resource usage. Availability won't be increased significantly.

Comment: To better utilize the resources of the VM. And I have to imagine that having many processes doing the same thing would result in a performance improvement over just having one. Each process is reading and processing message from a service bus using your NuGet package I believe :)

Comment: cool :)  True, if your service is I/O bound and not able to use up all available bandwidth using one instance. Adding multiple instances of the Service type - like you said - will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just need more partitions of the service? Have you tried using a different partition schema, other than the default single partition for services.

It will run one of your .exe for each partition. Remember if they use any communication and listens on ports, you need to use one that can share the port or use multiply ports for each partition.

Comment: I ending up going with this approach. Multiple named services work as well but using partitions seemed like it was more straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to create multiple instances (aka named services) of your stateless service type.

The word "instance" is overloaded for stateless services. For any kind of service (stateful or stateless), you can create one or more "instances" (aka "named service") of a service type. An instance of a stateful service gets a set of replicas, and an instance of a stateless service gets a set of "instances" (there's that terminology overload!). To put it another way, in both cases you get a set of things that belong to a service instance (named service) and will be distributed *across* nodes, never grouped on a single node. If you create another instance (named service) of a service type, that has its own set of things which can be grouped on the same nodes as another instance (named service), and in fact, instances (named services) of the same service type will even share the same host process (.EXE) when running on the same node.

Comment: can you point us to an example of this named services? thanks!

Comment: "named service" is just a different term I used to describe a service instance to help explain Service Fabric terminology. When you create an instance of a service and give it a name, e.g., "fabric:/MyApp/MyService" - that's a "named service."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with this answer. Dint you mention that "a set of things that belong to a service instance will be distributed across nodes"? If that is the case then how can we have multiple instances of the same service type on the same node?